# ymaps API. Как получить ссылку на географический объект?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Если открыть Яндекс.Карты и выбрать какой либо объект, можно им поделиться, тогда получим ссылку вида:

> https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCUeiHWj8B

если по ней перейти, нас переадресует на такой адрес:

> https://yandex.ru/maps/239/sochi/house/ulitsa_poyarko_5/Z0AYcQVgTUMBQFppfXl5cnxrbQ==/?ll=39.723608%2C43.583454&z=17

Вот самое интересное, что этот адрес сразу выделяет выбранный объект, и за это отвечает не GET параметр ll, а именно адрес страницы. Это очень удобно, точно знаешь что будет показан именно выбранный объект.

Собственно сама проблема.
Я уже второй день роюсь в документации к API и не могу даже намека найти на то, как получить такой адрес через API, а так-же как получить координаты из этого адреса, если нет параметра ll.

Задача в том, что бы показать пользователю на сайте карту, она нашел и выбрал нужный ему объект и ссылка на этот объект сохранилась. Позже, когда нужно будет показать, выбранный ранее, адрес, вывести ссылку с сохраненным url. А так-же, было бы неплохо вывести карту, на которой поставить отметку на этом объекте (для этого получить координаты)

Answer (score 1):

У Яндекс.Карт есть своя [url-схема](https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web.html?from=SO) с набором параметров, ссылки нужно составлять по ней. Для вашей задачи можно использовать параметр [`whatshere`](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode?from=SO) и передавать в него координаты адреса и желаемый зум.

На стороне API можно получать "выбор" адреса разными способами. Просить кликнуть в дом на карте и [получать координаты клика](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode?from=SO); просить [воспользоваться поиском](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search_results?from=SO) или передвинуть метку на карте; сделать [ввод адреса с валидацией через геокодер](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation?from=SO). Дальше дело техники — из API у вас уже есть координаты выбранного адреса, которые можно подставить в ссылку на Яндекс.Карты.